# How can i make the checkboxes to effect also in editore mode and when the game is running?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 checkboxes

```
public bool stateForward = false, stateReverse = false, stateRandom = false;
```

I want that i will be able to chose each time only one checkbox. But also in editor mode and also when the game is running. And when the game is running i want to make it effect on the game.

In the top of the script i added:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
```

I tried to do in the Start function

```
void Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (stateForward == true)
            {
                stateRandom = false;
                stateReverse = false;
            }
            else if (stateReverse == true)
            {
                stateRandom = false;
                stateForward = false;
            }
            else if (stateRandom == true)
            {
                stateForward = false;
                stateReverse = false;
            }
        }
        anims = GetComponent<Animations>();
        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ClonedObject");
        objectsToMove = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Robots");
        originalPosition = objectsToMove[0].transform.position;
    }
```

But i'm getting on anims: Unreachable code detected
And in the Update function:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (MyCommands.walkbetweenwaypoints == true)
        {
            DrawLinesInScene();
            anims.PlayState(Animations.AnimatorStates.RUN);
            WayPointsAI();
        }
    }
```

And in WayPointsAI

```
private void WayPointsAI()
    {
        if (stateForward == true)
        {
            if (targetIndex == waypoints.Length)
                targetIndex = 0;
        }
        if (stateReverse == true)
        {
            if (targetIndex == 0)
                targetIndex = waypoints.Length;
        }
        waypoint = waypoints[targetIndex].transform;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(objectsToMove[0].transform.position, waypoint.transform.position);
        objectsToMove[0].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objectsToMove[0].transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(waypoint.position - objectsToMove[0].transform.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        //move towards the player
        if (distance < 30)
        {
            objectsToMove[0].transform.position += objectsToMove[0].transform.forward * slowDownSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else
        {
            objectsToMove[0].transform.position += objectsToMove[0].transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (distance < 2)
        {
            if (stateForward == true)
                targetIndex++;
            if (stateReverse == true)
                targetIndex--;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you are never going to get out of your `Start()` method.  You have a `while(true)` loop that you never break out of, so you will be stuck there.

Instead of multiple checkboxes that you can only choose one of, just use an enumeration.  Unity will give you a drop down and you can choose one of the three available states.

`enum MyStateEnum{ Forward, Reverse, Random }
public MyStateEnum State;`

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to be exclusive, you should probably use a single `enum` field instead of three `bool` fields. Your enum would have values `Forward`, `Reverse`, and `Random`, while your `MonoBehavior` would have a single field of your enum type. This ensures that only one will be chosen at any given time, and the editor should show a drop-down for selecting which value rather than a series of checkboxes. This not only fixes the editor UI issue, but will also lead to cleaner code with fewer potential bugs.